# Removing gaussian noise layer after training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gaussian, tf.keras

I was wondering if there is a way in which I can remove a gaussian noise layer

```
tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise(0.1),
```

after using.

```
model.fit()
```

so that when using my neural net in applications it will not be affected by such layers.

```
model.save("network.h5")
```

Comment: The GaussianNoise layer only operates at training time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.keras.layers.GaussianNoise()` is a regularization layer. You don't need to worry about it during prediction. It is active only during training time.